# rspec subject and its method error

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to learn more about rspec.  I'm following a book "instant rspec test-driven development how-to".  It's pretty basic stuff so far.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm using rspec 3.1.3, ruby 1.93, and rails 4.0

I'm in the first chapter and everything has been great following along with the book. The tests all passed. Now I'm at a point where the book covers making the tests more concise using 'subject' and 'its'.  I've triple checked my code against the book and it all looks good.  Of course, the book does not talk about 'subject' and 'its'. It just provided the code and expects it to just work for me.

I'm getting an undefined method 'its' error on my test:

```
../LearningRSpec/spec/lib/location_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `its' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::Location::Initialize:Class (NoMethodError)
```

my test:

```
    require "spec_helper"

    describe Location do
        describe "#initialize" do
            subject { Location.new(:latitude => 38.911268,
                                  :longitude => -77.444243) }
            its(:latitude){ should == 38.911268 }
            its(:longitude){ should == -77.444243  }
        end
    end
```

Any ideas what I need to do to get this working?
Thanks for any tips or ideas.
-jc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`its` has been removed from rspec 3. You need to install an extra gem to get this functionality back: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-its.

Comment: Thanks, I've been reading up on 'subject' but did not know that 'its' had been removed.  Figures I'd get an outdated book.  Sigh!  But thank you!